# confidence interval for autocorrelation of t-distributed residuals

Tags: confidence-interval, autocorrelation, t-distribution

According to theory, R(1), the lag-1 autocorrelation of the residuals from a model fit to a time series of length n, lies in the interval

( z(0.025)/SQRT(n), z(0.975)/SQRT(n) )

95% of the time when the residuals are uncorrelated and identically Normally distributed. What is the corresponding interval when the residuals are non-Gaussian, e.g., t-distributed with v degrees of freedom? It is simply a matter of calculating

( t(0.025,v)/SQRT(n), t(0.975,v)/SQRT(n) )

or is it more complicated than that? Thank you!

Edit: Actually, based on doing some simulations, suggests that ( z(0.025)/SQRT(n), z(0.975)/SQRT(n) ) is the more likely to be the correct confidence interval. Perhaps R(1) is asymptotically Gaussian even though the residuals are not, due to the central limit theorem.

Comment: You're missing the standard deviation in both formulas. Check section "Basic Steps" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Thank you. The standard deviation is implicit in the calculation of the z-value.

Comment: The standardization of your variable to fit either the z or t distributions is one thing, what I am saying is that you're not mapping the values back to your variable's range. Either way, observing this detail, the answer to your questions is yes.

Comment: Thank you. Since R(1) is dimensionless, I would not expect the standard deviation to appear in the range. What do you mean by "yes'?

Comment: What are you calling R(1)? I understood it's the lag-1 autocorrelation. I don't get how dimensionality purges out the standard deviation from a confidence interval.

Comment: I am using the formula for R(t) from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation

Comment: Also http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/autocopl.htm

Comment: When constructing these bands your null hypothesis is that the erros have zero mean and standard deviation equals 1, that's why it does not appear explicitly in the formula, but it's there.

Comment: @lucasfariaslf Because autocorrelations are *correlations* they don't relate to the scale of the original data at all; indeed the standard error of autocorrelations (holding the maximum lag fixed but letting the sample size grow) of independent gaussian noise is asymptotically $1/\sqrt{n}$. There should not be a $\sigma$ in the formula (well, more precisely, there is but it;s only a function of $n$ and the lag and it approaches $1$ in large samples and as a result many programs just use $1/\sqrt{n}$).

Comment: Now I got it, thank you @Glen_b, and sorry for the misunderstanding, OP. So, after all, the answer to his question is indeed "yes", right?

Comment: @lucasfariaslf I don't think so. I don't know what a good answer is right now but I am pretty certain that's not it.

Comment: Some simulations with t(7) residuals suggest that the z(0.025)/sqrt(n),z(0.975)/sqrt(n) values are about right as confidence bounds.